# jQuery Mobile behaving strangely, not allowing page to load

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a mobile theme for a Wordpress site and having some issues with jQuery Mobile. On one page of the site, the page won't load or perhaps it does, since I can view the source but there is a white overlay with a swirling 'ui-icon-loading' in the middle of it. The Firefox error console is saying that there is an error in jQuery Mobile. If I use jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js, the error is: "TypeError: f is undefined" on line 8. If I switch to jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js, the error is: "TypeError: cells is undefined" on line 13906. Other pages on the site, which are basically identical in coding with only different content, load just fine with no errors. I'm stumped here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I missed adding `<thead>` to one of the tables. This was causing the error with jQuery Mobile trying to sort the table.